# GNUPLOT - Output Array of Stacked Images

Tags: gnuplot

at the bottom of this post is gnuplot sample code that plots an array of .dat files numbered 001 to 103 and turns them to an array of .png's. Below is the first and last image

[image]
[image]

The question is, how do I stack the 001 to 103 .png's on top of each other and produce an output array of 103 images in the process? So far, I've  managed to do **one** image that stacks all the combined data from 001 to 103.dat. See below

[image]

The bit of code that does the **one** stacked image is commented out

```
# Test.png - One merged data
#filename(n) = sprintf("ar-agn--DensT-%03.0f.dat", n)
#plot for [i=1:103] filename(i) using 1:2:3 with points pointtype 5 ps 0.3 palette notitle
```

But what I need is an **array of output** images stacked on top of each other.

Thank you all in advance!!!

```
#!/bin/bash

# Comment out the 3 lines below to produce all in one stacked image 
for FILE in ar-agn--DensT*.dat; do
gnuplot -p << EOF
set output "${FILE}.png"

set terminal png

# uncomment line below for all in one merged data
#set output "TEST.png" 

set datafile separator ","


set xlabel "x-units" font ",16"
set ylabel "y-units" font ",16"
set cblabel "y-units" font ",16"

set tics font ", 16"

set xzeroaxis 


#  Temp vs Density

set yr [0.0:8.0]
set xr [-3.0:6.0]

 set xlabel "log (Number density/(cm^{-3}) )"
 set ylabel "log (Temperature/ K )"

set cbrange [0.099949:10.2948]

set cblabel "Time (Myr)"

set palette  defined ( \
    0 '#0c0887' ,\
    1 '#4b03a1'   ,\
    2 '#7d03a8'   ,\
    3 '#a82296'    ,\
    4 '#cb4679'     ,\
    5 '#e56b5d'   ,\
    6 '#f89441'  ,\
    7 '#fdc328' ,\
    8 '#f0f921'  )

#  Series of subsequnt plots
plot  "${FILE}" u 1:2:3 with points pointtype 5 ps 0.3 palette notitle

# Test.png - One merged data
#filename(n) = sprintf("ar-agn--DensT-%03.0f.dat", n)
#plot for [i=1:103] filename(i) using 1:2:3 with points pointtype 5 ps 0.3 palette notitle


EOF

# insert comment into line below for all in one merged data
done
```

Comment: By "stacked on top of each other" do you mean superimposed onto the same square, as if you had applied 3 transparent stickers on top of each other?  Or do you mean drawn in a 3D view so that it looks like three slices through a solid cube?  Something else?  Can you provide a hand-drawn sketch or a link to a similar image to give an idea of what you want it to look like?

Comment: Hi Ethan, what I mean is superimposed onto the same square

Comment: So far I ether get an array of images '001.png', '002.png' etc, or an image that superimposes the whole array of images onto one square '001+002+...103.png'. What I need is an array of superimposed images  i.e 'image 001.png' followed by 'image 001+002.png' followed by 'image 001+002+003.png' etc

Comment: Sorry, still not understanding.   Do you want one output file, or three output files, or a single output file with a 3-frame animation,  or no output file at all but sequential display on the screen, or what?

Comment: @Ethan, sorry what I want is an array of 103 output files wit each consecutive file that represents the stacked data in the following sequential way: file001.png = data001.dat; file002.png =data001.dat+data002.dat; file003.png=data001.dat+data002.dat+data003.dat; file004.png=data001.dat+data002.dat+ data003.dat+data004.dat etc all the way upto file103.png=data001.dat+data002.dat+....data103.dat. So far I have individual .png's i.e data001.png, data002.png, data003png etc or the code can also do the one file i.e very last file in the sequence that I want file103.png = data001.dat+..data103.dat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close.  You need two iterations, one inside the plot command and one outside:

```
filename(n) = sprintf("ar-agn--DensT-%03.0f.dat", n)
outfile(n) = sprintf("ar-agn--DensT-%03.0f.png", n)

do for [N=1:103] {
    set output outfile(N) 
    plot for [i=1:N] filename(i) using 1:2:3 with points pointtype 5 ps 0.3 palette notitle
}
```